# After clicking on destroy with cocoon, how to recalculate invoice without destroyed record

Tags: javascript, jquery, cocoon-gem

**Context** 
I'm using the cocoon gem to create nested `invoice_rows` for `invoice`. Everything works as expected (deleting, creating nested records etc.).

In the `invoice form`I am also keeping tracking of the most actual `total_invoice amount` with Javascript. With my Javascript code I am able to recalculate the `total_invoice amount` when the `price, quantity or VAT` changes or when a new `invoice_row` is created with cocoon.

**Issue** 
The issue occurs when I delete a nested record. Following the documentation, I'm trying to use `cocoon:after-remove` to trigger the event, but nothing gets triggered after I delete an `invoice_row` in my view.

**Other attempt**
I also tried a click event on the delete button (see also the code commented out in the script). Unfortunately, the class of the deleted nested record is still picked up by my Javascript code and consequently is entered in the calculation of the `total_invoice amount`. (hence the `cocoon:after-remove` command I guess)

**Code**

invoice_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-container col col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
  <%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @invoice] do |f|%>
<h5><strong><u><%= t('.invoice') %> </u></strong></h5>
    <!-- headers -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-3"><b>description</b></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><b>unit price</b></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><b>amount</b></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><b>VAT (%)</b></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><b>Total</b></div>
    </div>
    <div class="border-invoice"></div>
    <!-- headers -->
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :invoice_rows do |invoice_row| %>
  <div class="reservation-details">
    <%= render 'invoice_row_fields', f: invoice_row %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div id="check">
    <%= link_to_add_association f, :invoice_rows do %>
    <div class="option-add-option-price">
      <div class="prices-border">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another invoice line
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="border-invoice"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"><b>Subtotal</b></div>
    <div class="col col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="field nettotal form-control"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">VAT</div>
    <div class="col col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="field vat-total form-control"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"><b>Total</b></div>
    <div class="col col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="field gross-total form-control"></div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-6"> <%= f.button :submit, t(".invoice_button"), class: "create-reservation-btn"%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

script for invoice form

```
 // $(document).on('click', '.delete-vat', function() { /* recalculate */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#check')
  .on('cocoon:after-remove', function() { /* recalculate */
    var result = 0
    var vat_result = 0
    var price = [];
    var quantity = [];
    var vat = [];
    console.log('yes')

    $('.price').each(function(i, obj) {
      price.push((Math.round(+obj.value*100)/100).toFixed(2));
    });

    $('.quantity').each(function(i, obj) {
      quantity.push(+obj.value);
    });

    $('.vat').each(function(i, obj) {
      vat.push(+obj.value);
    });

    var result = 0
    price.forEach((o,i)=>{
    $(".gross-total").eq( i ).val(o*quantity[i]);

    result += o*quantity[i];
    // console.log(result)

    $(".gross-total").val(result);
    });

    var vat_result = 0
    price.forEach((o,i)=>{
    $(".vat-total").eq( i ).val(o*vat[i]);

    vat_result += o*vat[i]/100 * quantity[i];

    $(".vat-total").val(vat_result);
    });
    var sub = result - vat_result
     $(".nettotal").val(sub);
  })
```

_invoice_row_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="row test">
      <div class="col col-sm-3"><%= f.input :description, placeholder: "Product or service description", label: false %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><%= f.input :price, placeholder: "Price incl. VAT", label: false, input_html:{class: "field price"}  %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2 "><%= f.input :amount, label: false, input_html:{class: "field quantity"} %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><%= f.collection_select :vat_percentage, @hotel.vat_groups, :vat_percentage, :vat_percentage, {prompt: "Select a VAT"}, {class: "form-control vat"} %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="field subtotal form-control"></div>


    <div class="col col-sm-1">
      <%= link_to_remove_association f do %>
      <i class="fas fa-trash delete-vat"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When removing items using cocoon, they are in general not *really* removed, just hidden. This is because the form (and all changes), are only saved when posting the form to the server.

So if you added a nested item, without saving the form, and then remove it, it is physically removed from the form (DOM). However, if a once-saved nested item is removed, it needs to be hidden, and the `_destroy` flag set, so the server *knows* which items to remove.

So the handle this correctly in your javascript, you can use the `:visible` selector. E.g. do something like

```
$('.price:visible').each(function() { ...
```

Furthermore, your `cocoon:after-remove` is now registered on the `#check` div? You should register it on a surrounding div of the nested items, e.g. the `form` itself would work better imho.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and detailed elaboration. It worked (as usual). Thanks as well for working on the gem and taking so much time to help people use it. You rock!